# Want to put my Ansible playbooks on a public GitHub but don't want my ansible-vault encrypted files up there. What are my options?

Tags: ansible

I have a bunch of playbooks that I use to setup/manage/maintain my homelab. They are currently hosted on a Gitea server in my homelab, but I'd like to put them on a public GitHub.

However, I don't like the idea of having my ansible-vault encrypted files on GitHub (even though my password is a randomly-generated 64-character password). What are my options? All of my encrypted files are under `templates/keys`, so that's the directory I don't want to be made public.

```
.
|-- README.md
|-- ansible.cfg
|-- group_vars
|   `-- all
|-- hosts
|-- roles
|   |-- role1
|   |-- role2
|   |-- role3
|-- playbook1.yml
|-- playbook2.yml
|-- playbook3.yml
|-- templates
|   `-- keys
|       |-- credentials_mariadb
|       |-- credentials_mongo
|       |-- credentials_postgresql
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to put your encrypted files on GitHub, you could consider one of the following options:

**1. Use a separate Git repository for encrypted files:**

You could create a separate Git repository for your encrypted files and keep that repository private. You could then reference this repository from your main repository using Git submodules or Git subtree. This way, your main repository can remain public while your encrypted files remain private.

**2. Use a third-party service to store your encrypted files:**

You could use a third-party service like **HashiCorp Vault** or **AWS Secrets Manager** to store your encrypted files, and then reference them in your playbooks using their respective APIs. This would allow you to keep your encrypted files secure while still being able to use them in your playbooks.